# renaming pandas dataframe indeces using index and column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe `df`

```
df
 Name 
0   A
1   A
2   B
3   B
4   C
5   D
6   E
7   F
8   G
9   H
```

How can I rename the ideces of the dataframe so that

```
df
 Name 
0_A   A
1_A   A
2_B   B
3_B   B
4_C   C
5_D   D
6_E   E
7_F   F
8_G   G
9_H   H
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**

Assign to `index` concatenated string, first cast it to `str`

```
df.index = df.index.astype(str) + '_' + df['Name']
#for remove index name
df.index.name = None
print (df)
    Name
0_A    A
1_A    A
2_B    B
3_B    B
4_C    C
5_D    D
6_E    E
7_F    F
8_G    G
9_H    H
```

**2.**

similar solution with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.set_index(df.index.astype(str) + '_' + df['Name']).rename_axis(None)
print (df)
    Name
0_A    A
1_A    A
2_B    B
3_B    B
4_C    C
5_D    D
6_E    E
7_F    F
8_G    G
9_H    H
```

**3.**

Solution with [`str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
df = df.set_index(df.index.astype(str).str.cat(df['Name'], sep='_'))
print (df)
    Name
0_A    A
1_A    A
2_B    B
3_B    B
4_C    C
5_D    D
6_E    E
7_F    F
8_G    G
9_H    H
```

**4.**

`list comprehension` solution:

```
df.index = ['{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format(x) for x in zip(df.index, df['Name'])]
print (df)
    Name
0_A    A
1_A    A
2_B    B
3_B    B
4_C    C
5_D    D
6_E    E
7_F    F
8_G    G
9_H    H
```