# renaming pandas dataframe using values in columns taking into account repetitions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe `df`

```
df
 Name 
0   A
1   A
2   B
3   B
4   C
5   D
6   E
7   F
8   G
9   H
```

How can I rename the ideces of the dataframe so that

```
df
 Name 
0_A   A
1_A   A
0_B   B
1_B   B
0_C   C
0_D   D
0_E   E
0_F   F
0_G   G
0_H   H
```

Basically I would like to use the values in the columns "Name" and restarting the numbering every time the value change..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with count, more possible solutions for concatenating are in [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46077101/2901002) :

```
print (df.groupby('Name').cumcount().astype(str))
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    0
6    0
7    0
8    0
9    0
dtype: object

df.index = df.groupby('Name').cumcount().astype(str) + '_' + df['Name']
print (df)
    Name
0_A    A
1_A    A
0_B    B
1_B    B
0_C    C
0_D    D
0_E    E
0_F    F
0_G    G
0_H    H
```